# Declared abstract and implemented abstract for interface

Tags: java, android

I'm struggling to resolve a "declared abstract implemented abstract" error. I'm in the process of implementing  call back interface to capture data when clicking a button in a custom layout, I am getting this error. I'm calling an override method in my activity (TestDialogInterface) but this doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Here are the specifics when trying to resolve the specific issue.

Error: 
"Class 'TestActivity' must either be declared abstract or implemented abstract method 'onPositiveClick(int)' in 'InterfaceListener'"

TextActivity class:

```
public class TestActivity implements TestDialogInterface.InterfaceListener {
    @Override
    public void onClickPositive(int someNumber){
    //do something
    }
    ...
}
```

TestDiaologInerface.java:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestDialogInterface extends DialogFragment {

    public interface InterfaceListener {
        public void onPositiveClick(int someNumber);
    }

    InterfaceListener interfaceListener;

    //check to see if interface is utilized in main activity event
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context){
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            interfaceListener = (InterfaceListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement InterfaceListner");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Select Date")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        interfaceListener.onPositiveClick(1);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `onClickPositive` != `onPositiveClick`

Comment: That's because you implement TestDialogInterface.InterfaceListener interface, when you implement interface you must implement all of it's mehods

Comment: Check the spelling. In the interface you have declared `onPositiveClick` but while implementing you are not providing implementation for this method, rather you have a method with **another** name : `onClickPositive`

Comment: Didn't the `@Override` annotation raise an error for you?

Comment: You guys are awesome. Thanks for the help.